# PHP don't follow redirects

Tags: php, image, http, redirect

I am on PHP 5.2 and I am opening image URLs using `fopen()`. But a problem I have been having is some images redirect my server from the direct image link to an image page (not an image, displays an image in a webpage).

I  have tried adding `max-redicts` to `fopen()` but it then won't open the url when I check like this

```
$opts = array(
   'http' => array(
   'max-redirects' => '0')
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$file = fopen($url,"rb", false, $context);
if(!$file)
   die("Couldn't open URL");
```

Comment: It can follow HTTP redirects, but the http stream wrapper won't parse HTML page responses and figure out which `<img src=` you wanted to snitch.

Comment: I don't want it to parse the page. I want it to get to the direct image, and not follow the 302 redirect that is applied to the image.

Comment: That's what it does per default unless you set `max-redirects` to zero. Also consider cURL (which *also* can do HTTP requests).

Comment: Did you even read the question? I have tried setting `max-redirects` to 0. But when I try to open the URL (see `$file`) it fails.

Comment: And I told you to not set it to `0`.

Comment: If I don't set it to 0 (above 1) then it will follow the redirects, and then later in my application tell me that the URL is not an image.

Comment: If people don't like you downloading an image, something could be said for respecting their wishes... However: follow the first time, get the resulting url, re-request the image but give the ending url as the referer and you probably bypass their check.

Comment: Genius! trying that now. EDIT: How do I add the referer on fopen?

Comment: I don't think its possible to set the referer on fopen